# ListView is available only for Android error

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my xaml code, has `mylist` `ListView`

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="mylist">
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>              
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Below error I am getting in `ContentPage`s **`.cs`** class

[image]

Comment: Well, have you set the iOS solution? Are you using Visual Studio or Visual studio for mac?

Comment: And what happens if you ignore the IntelliSense and you just do it? Any errors? It seems to me this is something strange in the description here, but it should work fine.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis - Thank you, It was just intelligence. You can write it as answer.

Comment: Strange, I will also pass it on to the Xamarin team, seems a bit confusing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you ignore the IntelliSense and you just do it? Any errors?

It seems to me this is something strange in the IntelliSense description here, but it should work fine.